# Mysterious properties in Vector classes in Flutter

Tags: flutter

The [Vector2](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Vector2-class.html) class has some mysterious properties such as `rggg` and `rgrg`. The documentation doesn't really explain them. `Vector3` and `Vector4` have similar properties.

What is the purpose of these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vector_math` package contains color manipulation functionality, and the mysterious properties are simply colorspace vectors.

So for instance is `c` were a `Vector3` that represented an rgb color, then `c.rg` would be a `Vector2` containing the r and g components of the color.